# If adding a new component to master.scss, browser-sync doesnt reload

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, browser-sync, gulp-sass

if I add a new component (_example.scss) to my master.scss and safe it my browser-sync reload automatically and show the style changes from "_example.scss". If I change another thing in this file and safe it, my browser doesnt reload... Any ideas? If I restart gulp, it works perfectly. Is it possible to reinitialize the files that proceed by browser-sync?

Heres my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');  
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var notify = require('gulp-notify');
var cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var changed = require('gulp-changed');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var reload = browserSync.reload;

// Compile
gulp.task('sass-master', function () {  
    gulp.src('./files/layout/scss/master.scss')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sass({}).on('error', function(err) {
            return notify().write(err);
        }))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', '> 1%', 'ie 7', 'ie 8'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./files/layout/css'))
        .pipe(notify('sass-master-task done, ready!'));
});
gulp.task('sass-ieframe', function () {  
    gulp.src('./files/layout/scss/base/ieframe.scss')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sass({}).on('error', function(err) {
            return notify().write(err);
        }))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./files/layout/css'))
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', '> 1%', 'ie 7', 'ie 8'))
        .pipe(notify('sass-ieframe-task done, ready!'));
});
gulp.task('sass-fonts', function () {  
    gulp.src('./files/layout/scss/base/fonts.scss')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sass({}).on('error', function(err) {
            return notify().write(err);
        }))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./files/layout/css'))
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', '> 1%', 'ie 7', 'ie 8'))
        .pipe(notify('sass-fonts-task done, ready!'));
});

// Serve
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init(['./files/layout/css/*.css'], {
        proxy: 'dumb-test'
    });
});

// Reload Task
gulp.task('bs-reload', function () {
    browserSync.reload();
});


// Watch Task
gulp.task('default', ['sass-master', 'sass-fonts', 'sass-ieframe', 'browser-sync'], function () {
    gulp.watch(['./files/layout/scss/**/*.scss', './files/layout/scss/master.scss', '!./files/layout/scss/base/ieframe.scss', '!./files/layout/scss/base/fonts.scss'], ['sass-master', 'bs-reload'])
    gulp.watch(['./files/layout/scss/base/ieframe.scss'], ['sass-ieframe', 'bs-reload'])
    gulp.watch(['./files/layout/scss/base/fonts.scss'], ['sass-fonts', 'bs-reload'])
    gulp.watch(['./templates/**/*'], ['bs-reload'])
    gulp.watch(['./files/**/*.+(png|jpg|gif|svg)'], ['bs-reload'])
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's a timing issue. Gulp runs tasks in parallel, and your reload tasks should really wait until after the build has finished. e.g. instead of

```
gulp.watch(['./files/layout/scss/base/ieframe.scss'], ['sass-ieframe', 'bs-reload'])
```

it should be

```
gulp.watch(['./files/layout/scss/base/ieframe.scss'], ['sass-ieframe-watch']
```

with a separate task

```
gulp.task('sass-ieframe-watch', ['sass-ieframe'], function(done) {
  browserSync.reload();
  done();
});
```

Better would be for your sass tasks to reload in the task itself using the streaming option. And the above style used for everything other than sass. This is so that browserSync injects the new css without a full page reload, but the reload is still required for js & html. See https://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp

Comment: thanks for your answer, still doesnt work :( – I need to restart gulp.. suckz

Comment: In addition to what @peterorum said - which is spot on - put in return statements in all your tasks and see if that helps.  Also look into the {stream:true} option mentioned by peterorum and moving the reload call to the end of the respective tasks..